# Excel VBA code for an audit trail. How to record deletion?

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code (not mine) for a simple audit logger in Excel that records changes to cells as they occur in a sheet called 'log'. It works fine for all instances, except when a user deletes a cell to leave it blank. In this instance it records nothing. I am not sure why this is. Can anyone help to update the code so that it records when a user deletes the data in a cell to leave a blank? Thank you in advance! James

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Value <> PreviousValue Then
    Sheets("log").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = _
        Application.UserName & " changed data in cell " & Target.Address _
        & " in sheet " & ActiveSheet.Name & " from <" & PreviousValue & "> to <" & Target.Value & ">" & " at " & Time & " on " & Date
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    PreviousValue = Target.Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it the whole code? I think you are missing `Public PreviousValue As String`. Try to place it at the beginning of your module (before any other macro).

Comment: Sorry, yes. I had 'Dim PreviousValue' at the start.

Comment: It's not `Dim`, it's `Public`. And it must be placed outside of any macro.

Comment: Thank you. I removed that line and added yours. It results in a type mismatch error at the penultimate line.

Comment: Hm, guess you've probably tried to edit more than one cell at one time. I'll try something quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work as long as the total lenght of the text in the cells (or their number) is not too high:

```
Option Explicit
Public StrPrevious As String
Public StrMarker As String

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngCell As Range
    Dim DblCounter01 As Double
    
    'Covering each cell in Target.
    For Each RngCell In Target.Cells
        
        'Checking if the value has changed.
        If RngCell.Value <> Split(StrPrevious, StrMarker)(DblCounter01) Then
            
            'Reporting the change.
            Sheets("log").Cells(65000, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = Application.UserName & _
                                                                         " changed data in cell " & _
                                                                         RngCell.Address & _
                                                                         " in sheet " & _
                                                                         ActiveSheet.Name & _
                                                                         " from <" & _
                                                                         Split(StrPrevious, StrMarker)(DblCounter01) & _
                                                                         "> to <" & _
                                                                         RngCell.Value & _
                                                                         ">" & _
                                                                         " at " & _
                                                                         Time & _
                                                                         " on " & _
                                                                         Date
        End If
        
        'Setting DblCounter01 for the next cell.
        DblCounter01 = DblCounter01 + 1
        
    Next
    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim RngCell As Range
    
    'Setting.
    StrPrevious = ""
    StrMarker = " | "
    
    'Covering each cell in Target.
    For Each RngCell In Target
        
        'Filling StrPrevious with Target's cell contents.
        StrPrevious = StrPrevious & RngCell.Value & StrMarker
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```